# Azure best practice for migrating to new Repository

Tags: azure, azure-web-apps

Right now we're hosting our website on an Azure web app. We've created a new repo for a complete overhaul of the site (as opposed to a new branch or something within the existing repo).

The switchover plan was to have two webapps - the exist one and a new one which hosts the new site - and use Azure Traffic Manager to do switch traffic from the old to new site. We tried this and got a "multiple domains point to region" error. We could easily work around this (new app in different datacenter, then clone of new app in original datacenter) but it seems like there should be a better way.

What is the best practice for achieving our goal of switching traffic from one app to another within the same datacenter?

Comment: You can find the steps to resolve this in an answer to a similar question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37746969/how-to-set-up-ssl-with-custom-domains-with-several-app-service-behind-a-traffic